# How do i scrape a paragraph which follows another paragraph with matching string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape for a paragraph that follows another paragraph with a particular text `"Interested String ZZZ"`

For example:

```
<p align="center"><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Interested String ZZZ</span></strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: small;">This is the paragraph string that i want to scrape out</span></p>
```

how do i do that in python?

Answer (score 0):

Use `text` parameter to match element by its text content, and then use `find_next_sibling()` to get the next `<p>` sibling element :

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> raw = '''<div>
... <p align="center"><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Interested String ZZZ</span></strong></p>
... <p style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: small;">This is the paragraph string that i want to scrape out</span></p>
... </div>'''
... 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, "lxml")
>>> [s.find_next_sibling("p").string for s in soup("p", text="Interested String ZZZ")]
[u'This is the paragraph string that i want to scrape out']
```